# How to copy a Mat to ROI?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm absolutely new to OpenCV and I'm trying to copy a pixel buffer to a part of the screen using OpenCV.

I do as follows:

```
//In the beginning I allocate the screen buffer and create a Mat for it
void initScreen(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {

      pixels = new uint8_t[screenWidth*screenHeight*BITS_PER_PIXEL];
      screenMat = new Map(Size(screenWidth, screenHeight), PIXEL_FORMAT);
      screenMat->data = pixels
}

// Here I'm getting the pixel data to display on screen and coords where they should be displayed
void onDisplayPixels(int l, int t, int w, int h, void* newPixels) 
{
      // So I set a ROI at my screen Map
      Mat roi(screenMat, cv::Rect(l, t, w, h));

      // And I create a new Mat for the new pixels 
      Mat newPixelsMat(Size(w, h), newPixels, PIXELS_FMT);


      // Now I need to copy newPixelsMat to roi 
      **But how do I do that??**
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Mat::copyTo()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto) like this:

```
newPixelsMat.copyTo(roi);
```